# Django Custom User

Tags: python, django

This sounds like a million other similar questions that have been asked but bear with me.

I am new to Django but not to Python. I followed **thenewboston's** tutorial on youtube so I have a general understanding of how the framework works. As a learning exercise, I want to create a "social network" type site where a user can register for a profile, filling in the following fields:

```
-Profile pic (file)  
-Bio + personal info  
-List with add functionality, meaning the user can press a "+" and add new things to the list. The final, full length list is what I want to store.  
-Random file upload field.
```

How do I go about extending the base user class? I'd prefer to do it from scratch as a learning exercise, but welcome the idea of using all-auth if there is a good guide.

Rather than closing the question as a duplicate, would you mind pointing me to the best guides for a beginner in order to do this apart from the official Django documentation?

Links to other threads would be ok too. There is a lot of info on the web for this and several pages use parts of the framework without any explanation.

Comment: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Comment: I would start with the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model). Since you only want to add extra fields and _not_ change the authentication behaviour, your best bet is to use the "profile method".

Answer (score 0):

Django All Auth documentation is good enough. You can extend your user profile like this:

*models.py*

```
class StudentProfile(models.Model):
    userId = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='student_profile')
    user_dp = models.ImageField(upload_to = upload_location, null = True, blank=True, width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=True)
    gender_choices = (
        ('Unspecified', 'Unspecified'),
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
        ('Other', 'Other'),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=gender_choices, default='Unspecified')
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    graduation_year = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank = True, null=True)
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    onboarded = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name
```

This is the student profile which uses the User (django in built auth) as a onetoone field. I have been using this in my project. If you want social login, using all auth is recommended. You can use the pre save signal/extend the default registration when user registers to create user profile. Like this:

```
class SocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):
    def save_user(self, request, sociallogin, form=None):
        user = super(SocialAccountAdapter, self).save_user(request, sociallogin, form)
        changes = 0
        try:
           profile = StudentProfile.objects.get(userId=user).first()
        except StudentProfile.DoesNotExist:
           profile = StudentProfile()
           profile.userId = user
           profile.save()

        if not profile.user_dp:
            url = sociallogin.account.get_avatar_url()
            avatar = download_file_from_url(url)
            if avatar:
                profile.user_dp = avatar
                changes = 1


        if changes == 1:
            profile.save()

        return user

    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        """
        Invoked just after a user successfully authenticates via a
        social provider, but before the login is actually processed
        (and before the pre_social_login signal is emitted).

        We're trying to solve different use cases:
        - social account already exists, just go on
        - social account has no email or email is unknown, just go on
        - social account's email exists, link social account to existing user
        """

        print (sociallogin.account.extra_data)
        # Ignore existing social accounts, just do this stuff for new ones
        if sociallogin.is_existing:
            return

        # some social logins don't have an email address, e.g. facebook accounts
        # with mobile numbers only, but allauth takes care of this case so just
        # ignore it
        if 'email' not in sociallogin.account.extra_data:
            if 'emailAddress' not in sociallogin.account.extra_data:
                return
            else:
                # Note: __iexact is used to ignore cases
                try:
                    email = sociallogin.account.extra_data['emailAddress'].lower()
                    user = User.objects.get(email=email)

                # if it does not, let allauth take care of this new social account
                except User.DoesNotExist:
                    sp = StudentProfile()
                    return

                # if it does, connect this new social login to the existing user
                sociallogin.connect(request, user)


        # check if given email address already exists.
        # Note: __iexact is used to ignore cases
        else :
            try:
                email = sociallogin.account.extra_data['email'].lower()

                user = User.objects.get(email=email)

            # if it does not, let allauth take care of this new social account
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                sp = StudentProfile()
                return

            # if it does, connect this new social login to the existing user
            sociallogin.connect(request, user)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem is not with extending User. I think you can not figure out how to manage this on DataBase.**

So, my solution for this is:-

```
- Profile pic (file)
- Bio + personal info
```

> For above two create a separate CustomUser model with 
>  **required fileds(Profile pic (file), Bio + personal info etc..)** and **ForgienKey(User)**

```
- List with add functionality, meaning the user can press a "+" and 
add new things to the list. The final, full length list is what I want to store.
```

> For this create a new Model UserSaveListModel with required fields.
>   On every + add button click save a new object of this for user.

```
- Random file upload field.
```

> Create a new Model UploadedFiles model. On every upload of file create a new obj for this.

You can also create seprate app for each one if you think they are gonna seprate module not just a functionality in future.

Comment: Do you have any links to similar code examples that I could follow? It's difficult without a sort of guide as a beginner.